# Apache Spark using scala output file containing parenthesis

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am joining two RDD's and using the following code. The output file contains parenthesis in between keys and values, I understand that it is because I am simply dumping the key, value pair to the output file. I am new to Scala and Spark. Please help, I need the output without the parenthesis.

The logic is that I have got two classes Data1, Data2 which contain the values of the input data and I join both of them using the key(finalKey)

```
   val input1=sc.textFile("file:///home//cloudera//Documents//flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv")
      val input2=sc.textFile("file:///home//cloudera//Documents//weather/sfo_weather.csv")

      val data1 = input1.map{
        Test12.flightDelays.Data1.apply

      }
       val data11=data1.filter(s=>s.airport1.toString().toUpperCase().equals("SFO")).map(s=>(s.finalKey,s.airport1))
        val data2 = input2.map{
        Test12.flightDelays.Data2.apply

      }
        val data22=data2.map(s=>(s.finalKey,s.max+","+s.min))

     val data33=data11.join(data22,1)

     data33.saveAsTextFile("file:///home//cloudera//Documents//11111.txt")

    }

    }
```

This is the output I am getting :

```
(20080103,(SFO,150,94))
(20080103,(SFO,150,94))
(20080103,(SFO,150,94))
(20080103,(SFO,150,94))
(20080103,(SFO,150,94))
(20080103,(SFO,150,94))
(20080103,(SFO,150,94))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map a key-value pair into a comma-separated string:

```
data33.map { case (key, value) => s"$key,$value" }.saveAsTextFile(...)
```

To map any n-Tuple:

```
data33.map(_.productIterator.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile(...)
```

I can't figure out exactly what the type of `data33` is, but obviously the first form (which uses *Pattern Matching*) can be expanded to any "hierarchy" of tuples or case classes (`Product`s):

```
data33.map { case (a, (b, (c, d), e)) => s"$a,$b,$c,$d,$e" }.saveAsTextFile(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Exactly what I wanted! Much appreciated sir!

Answer (score 0):

So, this feels a bit... inelegant... but if what you want is Strings in a textfile without parens, you might just try

```
def noParens( s : String ) : String = s.filter( c => c != '(' && c != ')' )
val data33=data11.join(data22,1).map( tuple => noParens( tuple.toString ) )
```